# Get predefined dimension and metric scope level details

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I need google analytics predefined dimensions and metrics list. In google, I got this link:

https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/metadata/ga/columns?pp=1

This list down all predefined dimensions and metrics. But they are not specifying its scope whether its belong to user level scope or hit level scope and so on. I need the predefined dimensions and metrics scope level details.

Basically I need this to get combination of valid dimensions and metrics.

Comment: It's really surprising that we can't find any documentation on this. This seems like such a common requirement. @ravi, are you able to find any solution for this?